# Android App crashes with exception "AndroidRuntime: android.os.BadParcelableException: Map size does not match number of entries"

Tags: java, android

Android Application crashes with 'BadParcelableException' exception in random places.

Crash log:

```
    01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.xxxx.app, PID: 32092
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime: android.os.BadParcelableException: Map size does not match number of entries!
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:864)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:841)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1592)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3872)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
01-09 14:25:55.521 32092 32092 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Please suggest the possible reason for this crash.I have browsed lot to find the reason for crash, but there is no article related to this crash.

Comment: You should post the relevant code, and **full** stacktrace

Comment: @isaaaaame i have attached crash log fully relevant to the exception. its not crashing in particular line of code

Comment: If you post an exception backtrace that consists of lines from non-user (i.e. system) code, you shall also specify *at least* what actual platform (*not* your app's target API version) and its version your app was running one (e.g. Android 8.0), so that one could look up the source code of the Android *at that specific version* to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @Jin-ohKang it was running on android 8.1.0

Comment: @NIrajkulal Would you be more specific - is it Android [8.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r42) or [8.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r72)?

Comment: @Jin-ohKang  8.1.0 it is

Comment: @NIrajkulal The relevant interface method seems to be `oneway void activityStopped(in IBinder token, in Bundle state, in PersistableBundle persistentState, in CharSequence description);`.

Are you sure that, in your `savedInstanceState`, you used either built-in `Map`s (like `HashMap`s) or other correctly implemented `Map`s and they can't be changed in another thread?

Comment: @Jin-ohKang  Yes, there is LinkedHashMap used in onSaveInstanceState of Activity, So Map can not be used in Activity's onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: @NIrajkulal You can certainly use `Map`s in the `savedInstanceState`. In fact, the framework successfully serialized every keys and values of the `Map`, so there's nothing wrong with the *contents* of your map. What's the problem, however, is that Android writes the number of entries (count) followed by the actual entries, but it found out that the actual number of entries was inconsistent with the original count. Please put the copied version (using the `clone()` method) instead of the original one and tell us back what happens.

Comment: Note that you shall never modify a `LinkedHashMap` from multiple threads; you should either use `synchronized` to prevent concurrent accesses or wrap it with `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

Comment: @Jin-ohKang i will check with the copied version. Thanks for the suggestion.